# Get all tds based on index using eq()

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the index 2 - i.e. 3rd column, (0 - 1st column, 1 - 2nd column and 2 - 3rd column), with the selector below I am getting only **1** td from the correct column, *however* I want **all** the tds in the index 2, how can I achieve that?

```
$($(selector).find("td").eq(currentCol)).each(function(i) { 
  Console.log("Left-", currentCol,$(this).width() - diff);
  $(this).css("width", ($(this).width() + diff) + "px");
});
```

Html:

```
<table style="width: 170mm; text-align: left;" class="te-tablerenderer"><tbody style="text-align: left;"><tr style="text-align: left;" class=""><td style="width: 64px;"><br></td>    <td style="">          <b>City:</b>        </td><td style="">          <b>City:</b>        </td><td style="">          <b>City:</b>        </td>     </tr><tr style="text-align: left;" class=""><td style="width: 64px;"><br></td>    <td style="">          <b>City:</b>        </td><td style="">          <b>City:</b>        </td><td style="">          <b>City:</b>        </td>     </tr><tr style="text-align: left;" class=""><td style="width: 64px;"><br></td>    <td style="">          <b>City:</b>        </td><td style="">          <b>City:</b>        </td><td style="">          <b>City:</b>        </td>     </tr></tbody>  </table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could loop through each row and grab the td of the col position/index:

```
$(selector).find('tr').each(function(){
    var td = $(this).children('td').eq(2);
    //do some other stuff with the td
});
```

Where 2 is the col position/index.

Note: From reading the documentation, the use of the .eq function will only ever return one result, hence why your existing code will only ever affect one element.

Answer (score 2):

How about using a CSS selector instead? [`nth-of-type`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthoftype) should do what you want:

```
$(selector).find("tr td:nth-of-type(3)")
```